Nginx ingress not resolving with I use host in spec rule
I am using nginx ingress with cert manager. Somehow this fails to resolve and I get a timeout when I try to access api-staging.example.io.
I am using Azure Kubernetes Service.
Everything works if I comment out host: api-staging.latticeai.io. Can someone help me out to fix this yaml?
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-api-ingress
  namespace: example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: api-staging.latticeai.io
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: example-api-service
              port:
                number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "api-staging.example.io"
    secretName: example-api-secret

